# How to parallelize this task using all GPU processors?

Tags: python, c, opencl, pyopencl

My Intel GPU has 40 shader units, 64bit width, and support opencl 1.2,  .
For example I need to calculate something like:

```
    c[gid] = a[gid] + b[gid];
```

I need to split this task between 40 units evenly.
How to do it? Also I need suggestions how to optimize some code for specific number of internal GPU processors.
Full code of example:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import print_function
import pyopencl as cl
import pyopencl.array as cl_array
import numpy
import numpy.linalg as la

a = numpy.random.rand(50000).astype(numpy.float32)
b = numpy.random.rand(50000).astype(numpy.float32)

ctx = cl.create_some_context()
queue = cl.CommandQueue(ctx)

a_dev = cl_array.to_device(queue, a)
b_dev = cl_array.to_device(queue, b)
dest_dev = cl_array.empty_like(a_dev)

prg = cl.Program(ctx, """
    __kernel void sum(__global const float *a,
    __global const float *b, __global float *c)
    {
      int gid = get_global_id(0);
      c[gid] = a[gid] + b[gid];
    }
    """).build()

prg.sum(queue, a.shape, None, a_dev.data, b_dev.data, dest_dev.data)

print(la.norm((dest_dev - (a_dev+b_dev)).get()))
```

Comment: If it supports device fission, you can divide gpu into single compute unit sub devices. Even without device fission, It still fills all pipelines equally if you launch a kernel with enough workitems. Since it has only 40 pipelines, you may be ok with just 800 workitems or whatever in flight threads it supports

Comment: If you have multiple gpus then divide your work into chunks and distribute them to gpus as fast and as more as they can compute. For example, have a queue per gpu, fill queues with work whenever they consume half of own queue. Or simply divide work in place and run gpus on their part, measure their performance, adjust work share ratio depending on current performance.

Comment: But why 800 workitems? What parameter of my GPU I need to check?

Comment: 800 is just random example. Depends on hardware. You can't query number of in-flight threads supported. You can query only number of compute units which have unqueryable number of shaders per unit.